# VB.net Excel sorting

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I am trying to get a macro convert from VBA over to vb.net and I am getting a type mismatched error and can't figure it out.  I am hoping someone here will be able to help me.

This is the code.

```
Sub SortRawData()
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oRange As Excel.Range


    Try
        oSheet = SetActiveSheet(mLocalDocument, "Sheet 1")
        oRange = mApplication.ActiveSheet.UsedRange


        oRange.Sort(Key1:=oRange("J2"), Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, _
            Header:=Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
            Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, _
            DataOption1:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, _
            DataOption2:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, _
            DataOption3:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)


             Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandler.HandleError(ex.Message, ex.Source, ex.StackTrace)

    End Try


End Sub
```

This is the code from the macro

```
Sub SortRawData(ByRef poRange As Range)

Set poRange = Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange


poRange.Sort Key1:=Range("J2"), Order1:=xlAscending _
, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
DataOption3:=xlSortNormal


poRange.Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                   Key2:=Range("H2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                   Key3:=Range("L2"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                   Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
                   xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, _
    DataOption3:=xlSortNormal


End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: On what line, do you get the error?

Comment: I am getting a type mismatch error on 
oRange.Sort(Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, _
                Key1:=oRange("J2"), _
                Header:=Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, _
                DataOption1:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, _
                DataOption2:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, _
                DataOption3:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)

Answer (score 1):

Simple change the first line like this: oRange.Sort(Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, Key1:=oRange("J2")_

Comment: Thanks, I finally got it to work.
Here is my result:
            oRange.Sort(Key1:=oRange(2, 9), Order1:=Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending, _
                 Header:=Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, MatchCase:=False, _
                 Orientation:=Excel.XlSortOrientation.xlSortColumns, _
                 DataOption1:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, _
                 DataOption2:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal, _
                 DataOption3:=Excel.XlSortDataOption.xlSortNormal)